# PHP string manipulation - insert values after specific piece

Tags: php, regex, string

I have a string val of `H: 35" V: 24 1/2"`
I can extract the `35` and `24` perform a metric conversion calculation then,
 (and this is where i'm stuck),  
remake the string to look like `H: 35" (89 cm) V: 24 1/2" (62 cm)`?

I found regex that could pull the int by

```
$str = 'H: 35" V: 24 1/2"';
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches, true);  
//Array ( [0] => 35 [1] => 24 [2] => 1 [3] => 2 ) )
```

But after this, how can I remake the original string and insert the array values after each of the pieces?

FINAL
thank you @AbraCadaver for the answer, however I found the fraction `24 1/2` was not getting calculated so here was my final

```
$str = preg_replace_callback('!(\d+( \d+/\d+)?")!',
   function($matches) {

        if(isset($matches[2])){
            $fraction = $matches[2];
            if( strpos( $fraction, '/' ) !== false ) {
                $ints = explode('/', $fraction);
                $fraction = $ints[0] / $ints[1];
            }
        }

      $new  = isset($matches[2]) ? $matches[1] + $fraction : $matches[1];
        $new *= 2.54;
        return $matches[1] . " (" . round($new) . " cm)" . "<br>";
   }
   , $str);
```

Comment: Have a look at `preg_replace_callback()`

Comment: Can you expand the string? With  the regex as you have it's hard to know if item 1, 2 & 3 is "one" number or not.

Comment: With a plain `\d+` pattern you cannot match `24 1/2`. What are number formats you plan to support? What about `½`? Certainly, you need `preg_replace_callback` to achieve the final result, but your current pattern requirements are too unclear.

Comment: That's my point to Wiktor. If the string is `"H: 35" V: 24 1/2 0 pieces";` the regex would make it look like 24" 1/20.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I plan on whole number and some would have fractions,  idealy I would like to treat the fraction as part of the whole number

Comment: @NineBerry thank you!  `preg_replace_callback()` looks promising

Comment: This is probably a better pattern for you https://regex101.com/r/HaEbr4/1

Comment: I would just replace `" V:` with `" (89 cm) V:` and `"$` with `" (62 cm)`

Comment: @Andreas I tried `preg_match_all('\s([0-9 \/]+)\W', $repeat_, $matches);` and got an error `preg_match_all(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash`

Comment: You don't have any delimiters. Add a delimiter and it will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `preg_replace_callback()`. Just add `round()` if needed.

Capture digits `\d+` followed by an optional space followed by optional digits / digits `( \d+/\d+)?` and the inch symbol `"`:

```
$str = preg_replace_callback('!(\d+( \d+/\d+)?")!',
         function($matches) {
             $new  = isset($matches[2]) ? $matches[1] + $matches[2] : $matches[1];
             $new *= 2.54;
             return $matches[1] . " ($new cm)"; //or round($new)
         }
         , $str);
```

Comment: is this a `curry` or `partial`?

Comment: i remember reading about "currying" functions but never reached that level

Comment: Well then you are ahead of me :-)

Answer (score 1):

After seeing the OP's implemented code added to the question, I must post a more refined solution.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/75856ac29dce588c9229a2c852150cc85538605a))

```
$str = 'H: 35" V: 24 1/2"';
$str=preg_replace_callback('~(\d+)(?: (\d+)/(\d+))?"\K~',
        function($m){
            return ' ('.round(2.54*($m[1]+(isset($m[2])?$m[2]/$m[3]:0))).'cm)';
        }
        ,$str);
echo $str;
```

Output:

```
H: 35" (89cm) V: 24 1/2" (62cm)
```

Calling `explode()` as part of your callback functionality means that you designed a sub-optimal regex pattern.  All of the components to be processed by the callback with should be individually captured from the start.

Some developers may find my nested arithmetic and function calls in the `return` line to be hard to read.  These developers may declare single-use variables if they like.  Effectively it says:

- Calculate the value in inches by adding the whole number and the fraction as a decimal value (or `0` when the fraction substring absent).
- Multiply the decimal version of the inches value by `2.54`.
- Round the product to nearest whole number.
- Wrap in `(` and `cm)` and `return`

The `\K` at the end of the pattern restarts the fullstring match so that the return value is merely appended to the end of targeted substrings.  This avoids the need to copy the capture groups into the `return` string.

Here is a [Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lqcZF7/1) of my pattern with the sample input which also provides the pattern explanation in itemized technical terms.